# Activity with Dialogfragment is always in the middle

Tags: android, android-layout, android-dialogfragment, dialogfragment

[image]

The image above is my current activity with a dialog fragment. as you can see dialog is in the middle of the screen but it want it to look something like in google maps where when I click on the button the dialog appears near the button:

[image]

=>

[image: result]

As you can see in google maps the dialog is not in the middle its near the selected button. This is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:id="@+id/edit_name"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:layout_gravity="center"
 android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/lbl_your_name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Your name" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/txt_your_name"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:imeOptions="actionDone"
    android:inputType="text" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Which looks like this:

[image: res4e]

As you can see when I edit my dialogfragment the edittext and textview are on the top of the screen but for some reason when I deploy the app they are in the middle.

Comment: https://guides.codepath.com/android/Using-DialogFragment#sizing-dialogs